# Windows Server 2008 R2 stuck at System Recovery Options

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

One of my Windows Server 2008 R2 server has started to go into System Recovery Options at reboot. I have tried to let it go through a System Image Recovery, which it says completes successfully. But after reboot it again wants to do a system recovery.

Safe mode doesn't work; it still wants to do a system recovery. Putting in the install DVD trying to do a repair actually brings up the very same System Revoery dialog again. Nothing has changed configuration wise.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

How about invoking F8 at boot and selecting the Last Known Good configuration?

Comment: Same thing: boots right back to the System Recovery Options